# Are Oracle client 11.2 and Oracle client 12 vulnerable with the Log4j security issue?

Tags: oracle, log4j, oracleclient

I'm reading about [the security issue with Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) and I understand this product is affected by the vulnerability. But is Oracle client 11.2 and 12affected by this issue?

I couldn't find if those products use any Log4j dependency or any documentation saying that those products are affected or not.

Are other Oracle products affected by this problem? Where I can check which dependencies those clients use?

Answer (score 2):

The link below will let you know which Oracle products need patches for Log4j.

Here is a section of the document that shows a list of Oracle products not required for a Log4j 2 patch.

> 5.0 Oracle products not requiring patches
>
> At this point in time, Oracle doesn’t believe the following products to be affected by vulnerability CVE-2021-44228:
>
> - Application Testing Suite [Product ID 4622]
> - Argus Analytics [Product ID 9171]
> - Argus Mart [Product ID 10383]
> - Banking Digital Experience [Product ID 12605]
> - Berkeley DB [Product ID 2051]
> - Commerce Platform [Product ID 9348]
> - Commerce Service Center [Product ID 9351]
> - Communications Converged Application Server [Product ID 5382]
> - Communications EAGLE FTP Table Base Retrieval [Product ID 11116]
> - Communications Network Integrity [Product ID 4491]
> - Communications Order and Service Management [Product ID 2270]
> - CRF Submit Requestor [Product ID 9641]
> - Database Gateway for APPC [Product ID 774]
> - Demantra Demand Management [Product ID 2100]
> - Enterprise Data Quality [Product ID 9464]
> - Enterprise Manager for MySQL Database [Product ID 11166]
> - Exalytics Software [Product ID 9736]
> - FLEXCUBE Direct Banking [Product ID 9111]
> - Health Insurance Claims Management Data Marts [Product ID 9313]
> - Health Insurance Data Management [Product ID 10643]
> - Healthcare Data Repository [Product ID 9161]
> - JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Deployment Server [Product ID 4781]
> - JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Enterprise Server [Product ID 4781]
> - JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Enterprise Server Platform Pack [Product ID 4781]
> - JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Server Manager [Product ID 4781]
> - JD Edwards World [Product ID 4839]
> - Mobile Application Framework [Product ID 11055]
> - MySQL Server [Product ID 8478]
> - Oracle Access Manager / Webgates [Product ID 5565]
> - Oracle Access Manager [Product ID 5565]
> - Oracle Application Express [Product ID 1348]
> - Oracle Audit Vault and Database Firewall [Product ID 9749]
> - Oracle Big Data Spatial and Graph [Product ID 11528]
> - Oracle Blockchain Cloud Service [Product ID 13444]
> - Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition [Product ID 2025]
> - Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher [Product ID 1479]
> - Oracle Client [Product ID 5]
> - Oracle Coherence [Product ID 2545]
> - Oracle Commerce Guided Search/Oracle Commerce Experience Mgr [Product ID 9633]
> - Oracle Communications Calendar Server [Product ID 8494]
> - Oracle Communications Contacts Server [Product ID 10696]
> - Oracle Communications Control Plane Monitor [Product ID 10764]
> - Oracle Communications EAGLE [Product ID 10768]
> - Oracle Communications EAGLE Application Processor [Product ID 11122]
> - Oracle Communications EAGLE Element Management System [Product ID 11125]
> - Oracle Communications EAGLE LNP Application Processor [Product ID 11118]
> - Oracle Communications Fraud Monitor [Product ID 10763]
> - Oracle Communications LSMS [Product ID 11114]
> - Oracle Communications MetaSolv Solution [Product ID 2267]
> - Oracle Communications Operations Monitor [Product ID 10761]
> - Oracle Communications Session Border Controller [Product ID 10750]
> - Oracle Communications User Data Repository [Product ID 11108]
> - Oracle Database (not exploitable) [Product ID 5] [See MOS Note 2796575.1]
> - Oracle Database Appliance [Product ID 9435]
> - Oracle Database Global Service Manager [Product ID 5]
> - Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition [Product ID 8512]
> - Oracle Documaker [Product ID 5477]
> - Oracle Enterprise Operations Monitor [Product ID 10762]
> - Oracle Enterprise Session Border Controller [Product ID 10757]
> - Oracle Enterprise Telephony Fraud Monitor [Product ID 13804]
> - Oracle Exadata Storage Server Software [Product ID 2546]
> - Oracle Fail Safe [Product ID 843]
> - Oracle Forms [Product ID 45]
> - Oracle Global Lifecycle Management Repository Creation Utility [Product ID 12746]
> - Oracle GoldenGate [Product ID 5757]
> - Oracle GoldenGate for HP Nonstop [Product ID 13046]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Claims Management [Product ID 9307]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Claims Management Web Services [Product ID 9311]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Disbursements and Collections [Product ID 9308]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Long Term Care [Product ID 9394]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Policy Administration [Product ID 9306]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Policy Administration Data Marts [Product ID 9312]
> - Oracle Health Insurance Policy Administration Web Services [Product ID 9310]
> - Oracle Health Sciences Argus Safety [Product ID 5710]
> - Oracle Health Sciences Clinical Development Analytics [Product ID 5563]
> - Oracle Health Sciences InForm [Product ID 9636]
> - Oracle Hospitality RES 3700 [Product ID 11596]
> - Oracle Hospitality Simphony [Product ID 11594]
> - Oracle Hospitality Simphony First Edition [Product ID 11591]
> - Oracle HTTP Server [Product ID 1042]
> - Oracle Internet Directory [Product ID 355]
> - Oracle Key Vault [Product ID 10221]
> - Oracle MapViewer [Product ID 1215]
> - Oracle MiniCluster S7-2 Engineered System [Product ID 12598]
> - Oracle NoSQL Database [Product ID 13373]
> - Oracle Retail Advanced Inventory Planning [Product ID 1785]
> - Oracle Retail Data Model [Product ID 2538]
> - Oracle SD-WAN Aware [Product ID 13941]
> - Oracle SD-WAN Edge [Product ID 13940]
> - Oracle Secure Backup [Product ID 1522]
> - Oracle Service Architecture Leveraging Tuxedo (SALT) [Product ID 5435]
> - Oracle SOA Suite [Product ID 1162]
> - Oracle StorageTek Tape Analytics [Product ID 10085]
> - Oracle TimesTen In-Memory Database [Product ID 1870]
> - Oracle Tuxedo Application Rehosting Workbench [Product ID 8485]
> - Oracle Tuxedo Mainframe Adapter for OSI TP [Product ID 5439]
> - Oracle VM [Product ID 4455]
> - Oracle VM VirtualBox [Product ID 8370]
> - Oracle Warehouse Builder [Product ID 9]
> - Oracle WebCenter Content [Product ID 2271]
> - Oracle WebCenter Content: Imaging [Product ID 4576]
> - Oracle WebCenter Enterprise Capture [Product ID 10212]
> - Oracle WebLogic Server (not exploitable) [Product ID 5242] [See MOS Note 2827793.1]
> - Oracle ZFS Storage Appliance Kit [Product ID 10026]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise CRM Client Management [Product ID 4860]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise CS Install [Product ID 9068]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise FIN Install [Product ID 8925]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise FIN Supply Chain Portal Pack Brazil [Product ID 8883]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise HCM Human Resources [Product ID 5071]
> - PeopleSoft Enterprise PRTL Interaction Hub [Product ID 5090]
> - Policy Automation for Mobile Devices [Product ID 5626]
> - Portable ClusterWare [Product ID 5]
> - Private Cloud Appliance [Product ID 10635]
> - Rapid Planning [Product ID 5235]
> - Secure Global Desktop [Product ID 8539]
> - Siebel Core - Services Security [Product ID 9001]
> - Sun StorageTek Tape Library ACSLS [Product ID 10088]
> - Tekelec Platform [Product ID 11269]
> - Transportation Management [Product ID 1991]
> - Universal Installer [Product ID 662]
> - Zero Data Loss Recovery Appliance [Product ID 11342]

Reference (need to login):

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=294496371045198&id=2827611.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=aof21bja3_4

Comment: Requires a signon link only goes to https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is the information in the Link also available somewhere else without having to provide login data

Comment: AFAIK, no it isn't.  Send your complaints to Oracle and their law firms :-)

Comment: (I assume that you mean available in some "official" sense.  If you do a Google phrase search you can find unofficial copies including this Q&A.  Obviously, there is no way of knowing if an unofficial copy is up to date with out looking at the latest version of the original.)

Answer (score 1):

That Oracle note says that patching the Oracle Client isn't needed:

> 5.0 Oracle products not requiring patches: 
> Oracle Client [Product ID 5]

However I see Log4j files in the Oracle Client 12.2 installation:

```
..\product\12.2.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\lib\log4j-1.2.13.jar
```

I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: We are also confuse their is not info about this product.
I've found those files in the Oracle 11.2.0 client :
```C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\oui\jlib\jlib\log4j-core.jar
C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\sysman\jlib\log4j-core.jar```

Still go no clues if this is impacted

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it uses Log4j version 1.2, which is not affected by the current vulnerability of Log4j. That's why it is listed as no patches required.